# REST API Integration with Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration, connected-apps

I'am creating a integration between our website and our salesforce instance. Use case is to save record entered in website as lead in salesforce. I'am creating a connected app but I don't have an idea what to put in the callback url. Can I put the example in the help text https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/callback?

Answer (score 1):

The callback URL is the URL that should receive the access/refresh tokens. This will be wherever you deployed your code to, for example https://www.example.com/oauth2/callback. Since you're in control of your own website, the URL is whatever you want it to be.

Comment: I am just curious, wouldn't the `web-to-lead` solve his requirement?

Comment: @ArnoldJr. Yes, one can use Web-to-Lead at a basic level, but it has no error handling, a low daily limit, and is often the target of spambots. This is probably fine for a small brick-and-mortar with low expected traffic, but larger organizations need to implement their own alternatives. For example, at my org, we'd have to manually enter the majority of our leads because we'd hit the the limit by early morning every day.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I hope you got my beer. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I did, thanks!